# How to get an ipv4 address via NetworkManager?

Tags: fedora, systemd, networkmanager

I run a Fedora 20 as a virtual machine for education purposes.

Default it has a host-only network interface that gets only an IPv6 address which is inconvenient.

I want to automate that on startup it would get an IPv4 address.

I was told to use NetworkManager, not by a custom systemd service.

How can I make it to get that IPv4 address for that network interface on startup?

Answer (score 1):

With

```
$ sudo nmcli connection modify p7p1 connection.autoconnect yes
```

NetworkManager is configured to get an IPv4 address for the interface p7p1.

This works on reboot.

To make it work manually, you need

```
$ sudo nmcli connection up p7p1
```

Thanks for lrintel on #nm, the IRC channel for NetWorkManager.